# Keras functional API: My model is only optimizing for one loss function instead of 2 loss functions while training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I have 2 loss functions in my model - Cross Entropy and Mean Squared.
I want my model to minimize both the losses but the model is only minimizing mean squared error during training.

```
def buildGenerator(dmodel, batch=100):
    
    inputs = Input(shape=(256,256,1))
    
    x = Conv2D(
            filters = 32,
            kernel_size = 3,
            padding = 'same',
            strides = 1
        )(inputs)
    x = BatchNormalization(momentum = 0.9)(x)
    x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)
    .........................
    ...........................

    outputs1 = Conv2D(
            filters = 2,
            kernel_size = 3,
            padding = 'same',
            strides = 1
        )(x)
    
    
    outputs2 = dmodel(outputs1)
    
    model = Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = [ outputs2, outputs1], name = 'functional_model')
    
    model.compile(
        loss = ['binary_crossentropy','mse' ],
        optimizer = 'Adam',
        loss_weights = [1.0, 0.6],
        metrics=['accuracy', 'mse']
        )
    
    return model
```

In this code, dmodel is another model. I am using dmodel to classify outputs1 generated by the model and then finding cross-entropy between input labels and the output labels.

This is how I am training

```
dmodel = buildDiscriminator()
dmodel.load_weights('./GAN/discriminator')
dmodel.trainable = False
x, y1 =  getGeneratorData()
y2 = np.ones((batch, 1))
model = buildGenerator(dmodel)
model.fit(x,[y2, y1],epochs=1)
```

I tried a lot of things like changing loss_weights, changing loss functions but nothing is working. My model is only minimizing the MSE function.

I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

I think using the discriminator model inside the generator is the issue but I am not sure.

Comment: How do you know the model is only minimizing the MSE?

Comment: I trained my model for hours and the accuracy of the binary cross entropy wasn't changing at all. Only the MSE was decreasing. I printed the graph for accuracy and mse. Accuracy was constant the whole time.

Comment: That is not evidence of the model only training on MSE, there are many other reasons why a loss can be constant. Are you aware that the model is actually being trained on loss: 1.0 * CE + 0.6 * MSE?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know whether there is a simple syntax to combine different loss functions, but you can try to define an own loss class. In another thread I found this code snippet that defines an own loss class that combines two other loss functions:

```
rho = 0.05

class loss_with_KLD(losses.Loss):

    def __init__(self, rho):
        super(loss_with_KLD, self).__init__()
        self.rho = rho
        self.kl = losses.KLDivergence()
        self.mse = losses.MeanSquaredError(reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.SUM)
    
    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        mse = self.mse(y_true, y_pred)
        kl = self.kl(self.rho, y_pred)
        return mse + kl
```

If you just replace the KLDivergence by the binary cross entropy then this should work. Additionally, you would need to alter the call() function, since this implementation applies two loss function on the same predicted y value, but you actually predict two different y values. In this case, your y_true and y_pred would both contain two values and you would need to apply each loss function on only one of them. I do not know if it is easily possible to take a single element from a vector (in the style of y_true[0]), but if it is not, you could work around this by applying a "mask" to you vectors by multiplying them with [0, 1] or [1, 0], depending on the value you need. With this done you can use the reduce_sum() function get you single value and apply the loss function on your new y_true and y_pred.

This is a little bit more complicated, but it should get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

When you specify 2 loss functions they apply to your 2 different outputs.
i.e. in your example binary_crossentropy applies to output2 which has a y_true value of all ones. And is the output of a non-trainable model.

It seems likely that you want to return a single value from model since you do not seem to have labels for output2. While you could define your own custom loss function that combines both losses on the same value, I would advise against it. If the output value is a single class prediction (i.e. pixel on/off) then binary_crossentrophy makes sense; If it is supposed to be a discrete value then mse makes sense.